# Realtime Database Web: Is it possible to only get values?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime db entries as shown below:

```
{
        <FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>:{username:<NAME>,message:<TEXT>,time:<TIMESTAMP>},
        <FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>:{username:<NAME>,message:<TEXT>,time:<TIMESTAMP>},
        ...
}
```

I am interested in getting only the values ordered by time in descending order and displaying them on UI. In Admin SDK I would do something like:

```
rdb
      .ref(`${rdb_paths.funfuse_connected_users}/${loc}`)
      .orderByValue('time')
      .get()
```

I see there's a method `orderByValue` but It doesn't take any arguments. How can we use `orderByValue` or anything to just get values instead of the entire object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database always returns complete nodes from the JSON, or a set of complete child nodes that math a certain condition. There is no way to get a subset of the properties for each child node.

If you find yourself regularly needing only the `time` property of each child node, consider adding another branch to your database where you just keep the `time` values.

So:

```
"Original_data": {
        <FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>:{username:<NAME>,message:<TEXT>,time:<TIMESTAMP>},
        <FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>:{username:<NAME>,message:<TEXT>,time:<TIMESTAMP>},
        ...
},
"Times": {
        <FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>: <TIMESTAMP>,
        <FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>: <TIMESTAMP>,
        ...
}
```

Comment: I see... can we order the data by time? can you share the syntax for same?

Comment: That'd be `ref.child("Times").orderByValue().get`, as now the value of each node under `Times` is the scalar that you want to order on.